# Summing Integers using Multithreading - Odd Results?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have two methods that both sum a set of integers in an array.

Sequential:

```
public static long sumSlow(int[] data) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i : data) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Parallel (I partiton the array, and use one thread to sum each part of the array):

```
public static long sum(int[] data, int threadcnt) {

    int partitionSize = data.length / threadcnt;

    Sum[] sums = new Sum[threadcnt];
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadcnt];

    for (int i = 0; i < threadcnt; i++) {
        sums[i] = new Sum(data, i * partitionSize, (i + 1) * partitionSize);
        threads[i] = new Thread(sums[i]);
        threads[i].start();
    }

    // wait for all the threads to finish summing
    try {
        for (Thread t : threads) {
            t.join();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    }

    long total = 0;
    for (Sum sum : sums) {
        total += sum.getSum();
    }

    return total;
}
```

With `Sum` being a `Runnable` class that is constructed with an array of integers, a starting index, and an ending index. When the object is ran, it sums the elements up according to the indices using a long member variable (I don't think I need to use `AtomicLong` since the data is always only used by one thread, but correct me if I'm wrong).

Now, I run some tests on both methods:

```
    // create file to export data
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("results.txt");

    // 20 tests
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        // create the array
        int[] data = randomArray(512);

        // sum the values sequentially, get time
        long sequentialStart = System.nanoTime();

        long s1 = sumSlow(data);

        double sequentialTime = (System.nanoTime() - sequentialStart) / 1e9;

        // sum the values parallely, get time
        double parallelStart = System.nanoTime();

        long s2 = sum(data, 2);

        double parallelTime =  (System.nanoTime() - parallelStart) / 1e9;

        // error checking
        if (s1 != s2) {
            System.err.println("Summing method incorrect.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String content = String.format("%f %f", sequentialTime, parallelTime);
        writer.println(content);
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

And here's what I get for this test (2 cores, size of array: 512)
Sequential time on the left, parallel time on the right.

```
0.000058 0.004966
0.000036 0.000973
0.000034 0.000649
0.000036 0.000724
0.000034 0.000627
0.000035 0.000690
0.000034 0.000817
0.000036 0.000665
0.000034 0.000793
0.000052 0.000940
0.000047 0.001023
0.000049 0.001216
0.000039 0.001821
0.000051 0.001186
0.000048 0.000826
0.000052 0.000918
0.000034 0.000802
0.000036 0.000723
0.000034 0.000587
0.000036 0.000917
```

Why are my results like this? To be clearer, why is the sequential method faster than the parallel method? Or am I just reading my data wrong / writing my tests wrong? I checked this for more threads and more indices, and the pattern was the same. Why is this happening?

Comment: Yes, per the linked answer, an array size of 512 elements is almost certainly not large enough to warrant the overhead of using multiple threads.  Try increasing the size of your array by orders of magnitude (5120, 51200, etc.) until you DO see an improvement with multi-threading.  Then you'll have an idea how large a problem needs to be before multi-threading becomes useful.

Comment: Try larger arrays, starting a new thread is expensive, it's not worthwhile for tiny arrays like 512 integers. Try to make the total runtime at least 10 seconds.